# Active directory physical setup

Tags: networking, active-directory

There have been many articles on various forums on how to setup mcrosoft active directory domain services. I am a bit new to the field, so please bear with my ignorance. I have a very basic query whose answer i am not able to find. I have an office of 20 people where i would like to deploy AD Domain services to have a better control. i want to know how should i set my network PHYSICALLY. I have a router supplied by my internet provider. Where exactly should i put my server? Can i plug my server anyhere in the network and connect the users through domain, or the main internet wire should plug into the server first and the users in turn be connected to the server. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaFWa.jpg) I hope i am clear. Should internet ‘flow’ from the server which has AD to users, or i can put the serverver anywhere in the topology.

Comment: This belongs to https://superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

In a small size network like yours, 1 server should be enough. It should be somewhere behind the router. Plugging it into the switch is fine as it will have a internal address.

You will need DNS on your server which will install when you promote to a DC. All of your computers need to look at your server for DNS. Your Server's DNS should have a forwarder to your ISP DNS or to a public DNS. It doesn't matter if you server or your router does DHCP so long as it gives out the server Internal IP for DNS.

What would I do:
I would plug your ISP into the Router, Your Router into your Switch, and all computers + server into the Switch.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I dont have a harware firwall. So if an employee brings personal laptop or mobile and connects to the wifi, how can i authenticate or control their access as their devices are not logged into active directory. Does my query make sense?

Comment: What do you want to control? Internet access? Or do you want to rescrict them from accessing any network resource except for internet?

Comment: I want to authenticate the external devices such that they can only use internet and not other network resources

Comment: Okay, So you have a couple different options. 

1. Purchase a Wireless Access Point that allows you to segregate your guests. 

2. Purchase a router that supports AD Authentication to access the internet and create policies to segregate.

Option 1 is probably going to be the best for your network size.

Answer (score 0):

You can place your server anywhere in the topology. It is not necessary for all user traffic to the internet to be routed through the server.

With small-scale deployments (less than 25 Users) I typically just put the server on the same switch and subnet as the users.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i will plug the servers and users as suggested by Devon and you. Just to add to my query: I dont have a harware firwall. So if an employee brings personal laptop or mobile and connects to the wifi, how can i authenticate or control their access as their devices are not logged into active directory. Does my query make sense?